# How to display long list in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

After noticing that my [problem is not a database specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550898/how-to-read-and-filter-large-realm-dataset-in-swiftui), but an UI problem I'm creating this new question here.
I have a SearchBar ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63298758/14677894)) that is used to filter a dataset from a realm database. This works so far well and fast. But when I want to display the result in a list it's pretty slow.

I've tried different approaches to display the elements. I thought the LazyVGrid could be a good solution for this use case since it doesn't create the view for each element but only when I scroll down and need to display them.

```
ScrollView { 
    LazyVGrid{
        ForEach(...)
    }
}
```

But this approach was veeeery slow and sometimes my app crashed.
So I switched to the classic approach with `List{ ForEach(...){ } }.id(UUID())` that is my current solution. The performance is okay. ~2-3 second for 15.000 elements. Additionally my CPU and memory is increasing extremely for the 2-3 seconds. I'm not using any animations or other stuff. For testing I just used a single line text to represent each element.

I'm looking more for a solution like: Display the first n results immediately. And when I scroll down and really need the other results the view for each element should be created only then.

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible example (say with Text subviews)?

Comment: I'm not sure what example you need. Actually it's just a list with ~15.000 Text elements.

Comment: Not reproducible with your LazyVGrid code snapshot and 15000 Text items in adaptive column. Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1